# How is Principal injected in method: SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I was reading on social login in the spring.io tutorials and I couldn't understand how the `Principal` is being injected in the public method `user`

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

Here is the [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_server_side_changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you are writing a method like

```
public Principal user(Principal principal)
```

And Spring is calling your method, Spring `BeanFactory` will try to find a bean named `principal` or a bean of type `Principal` to inject it into your method. So your code will automatically become like

```
public Principal user(@Autowired Principal principal)
```

Suppose you are going to call your `user()` method from somewhere in your code in that case you will need to pass principal as a method argument to your call, which you will do like

```
@Autowired Principal principal;
user(principal);
```

The Same thing Spring is doing it is injecting principal into your user() method